# IBM DB2 9.7, automatic foreign-key index generation?

Tags: indexing, foreign-keys, db2

DB2 generates PK indexes automatically, but is there a way to generate FK indexes 1) automatically by the database, or 2) through a script? Generating through a script is possible, but is there a ready-made script available somewhere? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, there is not a built-in feature to create foreign key indexes on DB2.
Though a script is always possible, you could get the columns that are part of the relation and then create the index. You get that information by looking at the catalog tables (syscat.references)